# How to set up image DIV for overlay animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have the following JSFiddle, which works correctly with fixed height and width: http://jsfiddle.net/69td39ha/2/
When you hover over, the animation is done correctly.

I tried to manipulate the above to use responsive method without fixed height and width: http://jsfiddle.net/cer1ts9x/2/
When you hover over, the animation is not showing up correctly.

HTML:

```
<div class="pageImgHdrSub percPadTop banner">
     <a href="google_events.aspx" title=""><img src="http://appcenter.clickmeeting.com/uploads/2014/05/google-calendar-logo1.gif" alt="" /></a>
    <p class="companyInfo">View Events Calendar</p>
    <div class="cornerTL"></div>
    <div class="cornerTR"></div>
    <div class="cornerBL"></div>
    <div class="cornerBR"></div>
</div>
```

Please help me modify the second fiddle to ensure the animation is showing up correctly

Comment: In what way is the animation not showing up correctly? Do you want it to cover the entire thing?

Comment: If you hover over the second one I am trying to use, the circle is not centered in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cer1ts9x/3/)

Hope that is what you want?

Basically edited 3 places:

```
.pageImgHdrSub -> width: auto;

.banner div{ 
    -moz-border-radius:170px;
    -webkit-border-radius:170px;
    border-radius:170px;
}
```

And line 16 of the js:

```
el.find('div').stop().animate({width:340,height:200},'slow',function(){
```

EDIT:

For more circle animation set width and height on the same amount. (in the js)
border radius should be half of the width/height to get a nice circle.

Comment: Looks like it. I will give it a test now. Thanks,.

Comment: No. The fiddle uses the code seen above. The code from the edit is in following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cer1ts9x/5/)

Comment: The circle is not accurate :/ If the image is a square what do I change as opposed it being rectangular?

Comment: Well, you cant fit a circle inside a rectangle. Just play with the width and hight values in the js function and the border-radius and take the solution you like most.

Comment: Well I understand that and I will play around with it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The picture was a square before, now you have a rectangular image - so you can't get a perfect rounded circle but changing the `width` & `height` in the animate function works somewhat fine:

```
el.find('div').stop().animate({
    width: 360,
    height: 160
},
```

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cer1ts9x/4/)